# Different bandwidth utilization in JMeter and in Browser

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to measure bandwidth utilization of a site using WireShark by simultaneously logging in 25 users and performing various activites on site in JMeter

I have recorded a script in JMeter to login and perform activites. But when I perform same activities for 1 user, in Browser and JMeter, I am getting different bandwidth utilization.

Expected result = Bandwidth should be same when same activites are performed in Browser and JMeter for 1 user.

Actual Result = I am getting Avg. 32k bytes/sec in Browser and Avg. 430k bytes.sec in JMeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is already in the [Jmeter Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does.

Comment: useful info for me...however I added think time to each request and the bandwidth is approx. close to Browser.. i.e I am getting 30k bytes/sec in Browser and 32-34k bytes/sec in JMeter.

Comment: Yep, that is already in the doc too. It's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time.